# Disable changing url router information Material-components-web tabs

Tags: javascript, web, angular-material, material-components

I am using Material web components for my framework agnostic library.
For the material tabs, when the tab is changed, the url route changes to the active tab.
For example in the demo :
https://material-components-web.appspot.com/tabs.html

when we change the tab, the url changes to  :
https://material-components-web.appspot.com/tabs.html#one

How do I disable the url change and still have the tabs function correctly?

This is concerning because my library is used by angular apps where the url route change is picked up by the app which then throws error or causes the app to function in an unwanted way.

Comment: how about using `javascript:void(0);` instead of `#number` in `href` attribute?

Comment: Or simply remove the `href` attribute on the tabs.